# take & print a screenshot from IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, printing, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot and print it right away. For some reason it doesn't response right...
I'm saving the screenshot into documents directory. Here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)printdoc
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
    NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1.0);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Screenshot.jpg"];
    [imageData writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:YES];
    NSString *myFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Screenshot.jpg"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myFilePath];

    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    if  (pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:myData] ) {
        pic.delegate = self;
        NSLog(@"CAN PRINT !!!!!!!!!!!!");
        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.jobName = [myFilePath lastPathComponent];
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
        pic.printInfo = printInfo;
        pic.showsPageRange = YES;
        pic.printingItem = myData;

        void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
        ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {

            if (!completed && error)
                NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u",
                      error.domain, error.code);
        };

        // iPad only printing

        [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}
```

Comment: I got rid of the word Xcode in the title (which will have little or nothing to do with the actual problem) in order to make things a bit more clear for people looking at your question, Roy.

Comment: and of course the Xcode tag has to be removed too. ;-)

Comment: Ok, I didn't get this one...I mean, why? haha

Comment: You only act on `!completed && error`. What is with the other 3 possible combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a little update! SOLVED !
Actually my code worked, it was my printer to do problems... it works great now with the code above! now I want to figure how to set it for iPad

Comment: did you get the above code to work correctly on iPAD ? if yes, please provide the full working code if possible.